# Logic used in dictionary to check existence of key

Tags: c#, algorithm, dictionary, logic

Dictionary cannot have two values with same key. please tell which logic/algorithm being used in determining whether the key exists or not.

Comment: **hashing techniques**. Isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eric Lippert explains this thouroughly in his [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx).

Comment: Not exactly a perfect answer, since it's just a link. It would be better to paraphrase the information here.

Answer (score 1):

How about method **ContainsKey** of Dictionary?

There are many ways to check for the key but I think this method is most graceful.

Answer (score 0):

Simple put it in try catch

if key exist will remain in try, else if not exists will come in catch

```
Dictionary<string, int> dic = new Dictionary<string, int>();

string str = "";
try
{
   int a = dic["keytofind"];
   str = "Key Found";
}
catch(Exception)
{
   str = "Key Not Found";
}
```

Comment: I don't like to wait of exception

Comment: In that case u need some microsoft guy who can tell u this. Like Eric Lippert.

Answer (score 0):

Trie data structure is used to store the keys.
 positive points of using this data structure :
 1. Saving of storage space.
 2. In O(Log(n)+constant) complexity can be determined about the existence of key.

More details about trie data structure can be found [here](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=usingTries)